# Impossible write into the AJXP_DATA_PATH folder ajaxplorer

Tags: permissions, pydio

I uploaded ajaxplorer "pydio-core-5.0.4.zip" to my server and after I extracted files into a folder in the server i request the folder to starting install but i get this message :

```
"Impossible write into the AJXP_DATA_PATH folder: Make sure to grant write access to this folder for your webserver!"
```

i made the folder : /data permissions to 777 and it did not make change ..

any solve ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'v got the same problem few hours ago.

The problem:
You put full permissions (777) to the data folder, but subfolders don't get it.

The solution:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 data
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo chmod -R 777 data
```

or

```
sudo mkdir -m 777 your_pydio_path/data/tmp/sessions
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but I was having the same issue with pydio-core-6.0.8. Also, I'm going to preface this by saying that I am a php noob. But I was able to resolve my issue without a `chmod 777` command. Instead, I made the nginx user the owner of the data directory.

```
chown -R nginx /path/to/pydio-core-6.0.8/data
```

And then made sure that php-fpm was running as the nginx user with the two php-fpm.conf settings

```
listen.owner = nginx
user = nginx
```

After restarting php-fpm, I was able to load the pydio page which went into the startup wizard.

Answer (score -1):

This command is so easy! But it's dangerous!

Go to `/var/www/pydio` for apache2 or `/usr/share/nginx/html/pydio` for nginx and try:

```
chmod ugo+x data
```

It's more protected!

Comment: Wanna expand on *why* this is dangerous, and why your solution is safer? Future readers will not necessarily be aware that making a given resource world-accessible is problematic...